# 3d scatter plot data from a text file

Tags: plot, 3d, scatter

i have a text file as below (data.txt)

```
A     B   C     D         E         F  
0     I  64  188.1308  188.1308  188.1308
0.13  P  16  188.1308  188.1308  188.1308
0.06  B  14  188.1308  188.1308  188.1308
0.03  B  14  188.1308  188.1308  188.1308
0.1   B  14  188.1308  188.1308  188.1308
0.26  P  18  188.1308  188.1308  188.1308
0.2   B  14  188.1308  188.1308  188.1308
```

I want to make a scatter graph that shows different color for each of different data in B column. a be the x axis, b be y axis and D be the z axis (or b the z and d be the y)

then for each data related to I (in column B) red for example, B be blue and P be yellow.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: What language are you trying to accomplish this in?